# How do I search and open links using the keyboard?

Tags: firefox, keyboard

In Google Chrome, I can search a page for keywords, and when over a link, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open that link. This makes keyboard navigation relatively effective.

I haven't been able to find an equivalent for Firefox.

Is there such functionality or is there a plugin that would perform this function?

Comment: "when over a page" you mean "when over a **link**"?

Comment: yes, that's right. Thank you for clarifycation

Comment: It looks like you have added solution information to your question, which makes it very confusing.  Super User's purpose is to build a knowledgebase, and it relies on the structure where questions are questions and answers are solutions to the question.  The edit seems to refer to DavidPostill's answer.  If so, the entire edit should be a comment on that answer, or the information on the plug-in should be another answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### How do I search and open links using the keyboard?

Press <kbd>'</kbd> (Quick Find Link) to search.

When you have found the correct matching link press

- <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Open Link) (Windows and Linux)
- <kbd>Return</kbd> (Open Link) (Mac OS X)

---

[image]

[image]

Source [Firefox Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts](http://www.accessfirefox.org/Firefox_Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, even better than what I was looking for.

Comment: I was about to ask a question: `Jump to links on internet browsers (i.e. Firefox, Chrome) with keyboard shotcuts/ fuzzy search?` then SuperUser suggest this. This in combination with `Firemacs` add-on makes the mouse almost obsolete. Awesome!

Comment: Just did. I also mentioned the `Firemacs` add-on to make a complete set :). You are welcome to upvote my coment :D

Answer (score 2):

The [my-keyboard-navigator addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/my-keyboard-navigator/) allows you to do most of your navigation with the keyboard. This addon also allows you to tie keyboard shortcuts to menu items that normally don't have keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I installed the addon, it's pretty epic.